# How do I include the gizmo in my simulation?

Tags: c#, 3d, unity

My company is developing 3D simulation program using Unity 5.x and we need a gizmo in our solution. My goal is to displaying that a factory is building.

I don't know how do programmatically use Unity Engine. How do I include a gizmo like the gizmo in the scene view, or the one in the image?

[image: The Unity 3D gizmo]

Comment: I would just recreate that thing as a 3d model and keep it in the corner of the screen with its rotation synchronized to that of the camera.

Answer (score 2):

The gizmo you are referring to is deliberately for display in the Unity Editor. With use of the `UnityEditor` libraries, you have some control over it; however, this does not help you in the final build. The easiest solution removes all programming requirements: **build your own!**

### Issues with using the Unity gizmo in a final build

While there is probably a way to export this gizmo to your final build, you have two issues:

1. Using this specific asset can be tricky, due to it not being provide with such intentions. It *may* involve more programming, which as you say, you are completely unfamiliar with.
2. The gizmo is not intended for final product display. There is likely a legal issue in that they are not really giving you permission to use it in your own software. If you *really* must use this variation, and solve the initial problem of retrieving the asset, you could always [contact the Unity legal team](http://legal@unity3d.com) and simply ask. I don't see why they would have a problem, but its best practice to make sure.

### Building your own gizmo

There is an easy solution here. Make your own gizmo! In essence, the gizmo is just a cube with some cones sticking out of it. Someone with a basic understanding of 3D modelling would be able to create their own version quite quickly, in practically any 3D modelling software. You could also create a variation using the basic geometric shapes provided in Unity, if you *really* had to.

[The colour scheme follows a common standard](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/79561/why-are-x-y-and-z-axes-represented-by-red-green-and-blue); across many pieces of software, red is often the colour of the X-axis, green is often the colour of the Y-axis, and blue is often the colour of the Z-axis. You will probably want to stick to these colours, as the uniformity greatly facilitates user familiarity.

Apart from that, you should tailor the gizmo to your own style preference or need. All it intends to represent is the direction of the 3 axis. The fact that it does so with cones is nothing particularly important - you may find that other shapes better suit your needs. Play around, and find out what works best for you.

Comment: As a final warning, always check that your project is on board with the terms of use. I have had trouble finding the specifics, but some variations of "simulators" are outright banned through the terms of service for using Unity. If your project falls within a banned category, you could be liable for lawsuit just by releasing it. As far as I can remember, Unity only disallows *military* simulators, so you *should* be fine.

Comment: [According to ux stackexchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/79561/why-are-x-y-and-z-axes-represented-by-red-green-and-blue), the XYZ=RGB convention is pretty standard.